# expireddomains.net - The export function is not available anymore

Tags: export, domain

Мне нужно экспортировать домены с сайта expireddomains.net, но у меня выходит ошибка `The export function is not available anymore.`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же у меня здесь только 2 кнопки, хотя у моего знакомого их 5. Как раз среди этих кнопок должна быть кнопка экспорта доменов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аккаунт я создал 03.12, немного больше 2 недель назад.

Как мне можно экспортировать домены? Почему у меня это не доступно?